# Swapping tabs in vaadin accordian

Tags: java, accordion, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin accordion in my project, can some one please help me to implement this functionality, where when i click on a tab in the accordion, it has to move one position up, i.e on clicking on a accordion tab, it has to swap itself with the tab above it.

I have tried to use the tab index and swap it, but only the tab gets swapped but the content of those tabs remains unswapped.

Can some one please suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: You tried [this](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#setTabPosition%28com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.Tab,%20int%29) method? Please post your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help, i finally figured it out myself, I was using .replaceComponent function which was only swaping the tab but not content of that tab.

Answer (score 1):

1. First find the position of the tab which you just clicked using.

   `int pos = sample.getTabPosition(sample.getTab(sample.getSelectedTab()));`
2. Now `pos-1` gives the position of the previous tab.
3. Now get both the Tabs.

   `Tab clickTab = sample.getTab(pos);`
   `Tab preTab = sample.getTab(pos-1);`
4. Now use .setTabPosition to move the tab.

   `sample.setTabPosition(preTab, pos);`
   `sample.setTabPosition(clickTab, pos-1);`